# NetSuite SCA -- Edits Made to Footer Not Showing Up

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

I made changes in the footer template to add a section and edited the css so it looked like I wanted but there is no trace of the new divs on the site. Am I missing something? I edited the shopping.css and footer tpl and did a cache refresh. Thanks!

Comment: what version of SCA?

Comment: Hey it is elbrus

Answer (score 0):

With elbrus you should have a development environment on a local machine.

The dev environment is based on some gulp scripts and requires a node version <= 10

You can test your changes without publishing by

```
gulp clean && gulp local
```

and then access your site at `/_ssp_url_root_/shopping-local.ssp`

you can make changes and reload the page to see the changes real time.

once you are done you can

```
gulp deploy
```

Your login has to have a role that is not Administrator nor Full Access so that's a bit of a pain to set up.